# Mediawiki doesnt show images

Tags: mediawiki

I have restored an old mediawiki database from about 2013-2015 on an current Ubuntu with mysql. Everything works fine after the database update. My only problem is, that images on the page are not been shown. I get the message "Error creating the preview image: file is missing". But the images should come from the database. I have checked out the usual error sources like /usr/bin/ convert and $wgUseImageMagick = true;

Any suggestions?

BR
Axel

Comment: maybe rebuild indexes and BLOBs?

Answer (score 0):

MediaWiki stores images not in the database but in the filesystem (see `$wgUploadDirectory` setting in `LocalSettings.php`). You have to restore it and make it readable and writeable to the web-server.

Answer (score 0):

As Alexander mentioned, check and see if `$wgUploadDirectory` is set to a correct directory that contains images for your MediaWiki installation. If you haven't customized your Mediawiki much, it should be `YOUR_MEDIAWIKI_INSTALL_DIR/images`. You also need to set proper permission for the images so that thumbnails can be generated for an image. Usually, permission on images directory should be 755.